# Verificação de rotação em javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5, css3

Existe alguma modo de verificar a rotação de uma `div` em `javascript`, por exemplo a verificação de `style` `left` é `offsetLeft`, alguém poderia me dizer como ficaria a de rotação?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tente isso:

```
var el = document.getElementById("complex-transform");
var st = window.getComputedStyle(el, null);
var tr = st.getPropertyValue("-webkit-transform") ||
     st.getPropertyValue("-moz-transform") ||
     st.getPropertyValue("-ms-transform") ||
     st.getPropertyValue("-o-transform") ||
     st.getPropertyValue("transform") ||
     "fail...";

// With rotate(30deg)...
// matrix(0.866025, 0.5, -0.5, 0.866025, 0px, 0px)
console.log('Matrix: ' + tr);

// rotation matrix - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix

var values = tr.split('(')[1];
values = values.split(')')[0];
values = values.split(',');
var a = values[0];
var b = values[1];
var c = values[2];
var d = values[3];

var angle = Math.round(Math.atan2(b, a) * (180/Math.PI));

// works!
console.log('Rotate: ' + angle + 'deg');
```

#### [Demonstração](http://jsfiddle.net/chriscoyier/459jS/112/)

E para uma explicação mais detalhada, segue a fonte do código: [CSS-Tricks publicado por Chris Coyier](http://css-tricks.com/get-value-of-css-rotation-through-javascript/).

Answer (score 5):

O principio matemático acaba por ser sempre o mesmo, e a resposta do [@Gabriel Vítor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/7693/223) já lida muito bem com o problema.

Deixo uma função com base em jQuery para recolher o valor da rotação de determinado elemento:

[**Exemplo no JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/QLETC/)

#### Função

```
function rotacaoEmGraus(obj) {
    var matrix = obj.css("-webkit-transform") ||
    obj.css("-moz-transform")    ||
    obj.css("-ms-transform")     ||
    obj.css("-o-transform")      ||
    obj.css("transform");

    var angle = 0;

    if (matrix !== 'none') {
        var values = matrix.split('(')[1].split(')')[0].split(','),
            angle = Math.round(Math.atan2(values[1], values[0]) * (180/Math.PI));
    }

    return (angle < 0) ? angle +=360 : angle;
}
```

#### Utilização

```
var angulo = rotacaoEmGraus($('#bubu'));
```

---

<sup>Créditos para a versão original da função para o @Twist [nesta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11840120/352449) e o @andreacanton [nesta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16435788/352449) do SOEN.</sup>